# Python Email is not coming as a single body

Tags: python, email

Code for sending email via python-3: 

(here, df1 is dataframe, s is smtp server object)

```
part1 = MIMEText(df1.to_html(index=False,col_space=1000),'html',"utf-8")
part2 = MIMEText(message, 'plain',"utf-8")

msg.attach(part1)
msg.attach(part2)

s.sendmail(MY_ADDRESS,email, msg.as_string())
```

This is not coming as single body.
part1 is coming as body for email and part2 is coming as attachment.
I need to have it as single body for email.

Comment: to_html gives you string which you can append to message and use MIMEText only once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
msg_text = df1.to_html(index=False,col_space=1000)
msg_text = message + msg_text

part1 = MIMEText(msg_text , 'html',"utf-8")
msg.attach(part1)

s.sendmail(MY_ADDRESS,email, msg.as_string())
```

**MIMEText** should be used only once.

 Do all the attachment in the string previously.